# Testing with RSpec and Action Mailer: Clearing enqueued emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer, rails-activejob

The Active Job Test Helper provides the helpful method, clear_enqueued_jobs.

Is there an equivalent for Action Mailer to clear enqueued emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can configure rspec to clear the mailers before each test like:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear
  end
end
```

In case of enqueue mails, Active Job Test Helper is included in ActiveMailer::TestHelper so you should be able to use the `clear_enqueued_jobs` method too.

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/test_helper.rb#L9

Comment: That clears the number of emails sent, not the enqueued ones.  You could also write that as ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []

Comment: @bagofcole I've updated the answer let me know if that works.

Comment: I have confirmed it works.  Would be nice if that was in the docs: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/TestHelper.html.  @JCorcuera You should think about contributing!